# Polynomial of Degree 3 Solutions

Tags: polynomials, roots, irreducible-polynomials

If $p(x) \in F[x]$ is of degree $3$, and $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3$, show that $p(x)$ is irreducible over $F$ if there is no element $r\in F$ such that $a_0+a_1r+a_2r^2+a_3r^3 =0$.

If $p(x)$ is reducible, then there exists $ax + b$ such that $a, b \in F$ and $a\ne 0$. And $p(x) = (ax + b)(cx^2 + dx + e)$. Then an $r$ exists such that $p(r) = 0$.
Is that how you're supposed to tackle it?